# Conditionally securing routes (user registration flow)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I need to implement registration flow using react-router-4. Flow consist of following steps:

1. Create account (email/pass)
2. Confirm email
3. Create profile (profile details like City, Age etc, required fields)

Application requirements:

- if user not logged in, he always should be redirected to `Login` page
- if user logged in, but email not confirmed, he should always be redirect to `ConfirmEmail` page (regardless of what URL he type in url address bar, even after loading app after few days)
- if user confirmed email, but didn't yet created profile, I want him to always be redirected to `CreateProfile` page

So if user didn't finished some step I want always redirect him to this step (even after reloading application and regardless of what URL he type in browser).

As an option I want to restrict user from accessing `ConfirmEmail` page if he already confirmed it (or restrict access to `CreateProfile` page if he already created profile).

How to *elegantly*  implement this logic using React router 4? I think it's a core/fundamental feature of application, so I'm looking for good, scalable solution.

Also i'm using Redux, so please note that at some point I already have following variables in Redux state: `isLoggedIn`,  `isEmailConfirmed`, `isProfileCreated`.

Thanks.

Comment: Tomasz answer is good, you should also use [Redux Persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to persist your redux store in [LocalForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) or LocalStorage

Comment: What do you mean by implementing Registration after logging in. How do you login to your application without registering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify how or when `isLoggedIn`,  `isEmailConfirmed`, `isProfileCreated` will be set so I assumed they will be already somehow set in the redux store before rendering starts.

I think that best tool for this task will be to use inline `Route` rendering similar to [auth workflow example in RR4 docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow).

I have made [sample CRA app](https://github.com/Tomekmularczyk/so-auth-example) that does what you require.

If you change values of properties in **redux/index.js**:

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  isEmailConfirmed: false,
  isProfileCreated: false,
}
```

... the app will use it to render appropriate view, no matter what URL you try to access. For example, if you set **isEmailConfirmed=true** and **isProfileCreated=false** then the only route you will have access is `/create-profile` (CreateProfile component). 
If the user however completed every step of registration steps and **isProfileCreated=true** he will then have access to every route except those of registration.

Enhanced `Route` named `AuthorizedRoute`:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const AuthorizedRoute = ({ component: Component, isProfileCreated, isEmailConfirmed, isLoggedIn, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => {
    //-- if user is fully registered - grant him every route except registration steps.
    if (isProfileCreated) {
      if (['/', '/create-account', '/create-profile', '/confirm-email'].includes(props.location.pathname)) {
        return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
      } else {
        return <Component {...props} />
      }
    }

    //-- user is not fully registered so he needs to be redirected to next step...
    if (isEmailConfirmed) {
      if (props.location.pathname === '/create-profile') {
        return <Component {...props} />
      } else {
        return <Redirect to="/create-profile" />
      }
    }
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      if (props.location.pathname === '/confirm-email') {
        return <Component {...props} />
      } else {
        return <Redirect to="/confirm-email" />
      }
    }

    //-- ... or allowed to use `Login` or `CreateAccount` page
    if (props.location.pathname === '/' || props.location.pathname === '/create-account') {
      return <Component {...props} />
    }
    return <Redirect to="/" />
  }} />
)

export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    isProfileCreated: state.isProfileCreated,
    isEmailConfirmed: state.isEmailConfirmed,
    isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn,
  }),
)(AuthorizedRoute)
```

And here are defined components that are aware of this logic:

```js
class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav>
          <Link to="/">login</Link>
          <Link to="/create-account">create account</Link>
          <Link to="/confirm-email">confirm email</Link>
          <Link to="/create-profile">create profile</Link>
          <Link to="/dashboard">dashboard</Link>
        </nav>
        <Switch>
          <AuthorizedRoute exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <AuthorizedRoute path="/create-account" component={CreateAccount} />
          <AuthorizedRoute path="/confirm-email" component={ConfirmEmail} />
          <AuthorizedRoute path="/create-profile" component={CreateProfile} />
          <AuthorizedRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I think the hardest part is to actually correctly identify the user and what he is allowed or not to do. Other than that it's just a matter of identifying route he is trying to access and rendering that route or redirecting.

Comment: There is no Login page here.

Comment: @zarcode You are right. I forgot about that and I made changes to reflect that.